Motorized Valve Wiring with ESP32
I am looking to connect this motorized valve with circuit as follows with a ESP32
https://www.sensoware.com/docs/electrical-connections/sa301/
I am planning to use a relay to trigger the Red wire and Green Wire.
So what is the transistor I have to use to drive the relay. (I don't want to use relay board available in market)
Kindly help.

You need a 12V relay which should be capable of supplying 1.5A as said in your reference. Such a tiny relay can be trigger with any NPN transistor. Like a common BC817,BC846 and any thing else around.

Also add a free-wheeling / flyback diode across the relay.
